# Accessing individual types of variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I am creating a lua binding in C++11. I want to process each type in a variadic template.

I was thinking I could do something like this, except using `Params...` represents all of the types inside of it, and not a the next single type inside of it like variadic function parameters do.

```
template <class T, typename ReturnType, typename... Params>
struct MemberFunctionWrapper <ReturnType (T::*) (Params...)>
{

    static int CFunctionWrapper (lua_State* luaState)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof...(Params); i++)
        {
             //I want to get the next type, not all of the types
             CheckLuaValue<Params...>();
             //Do other stuff
        }
    }
};
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by simply expanding after the function call, into something that can be expanded to.

```
// put this in your namespace
struct Lunch { template<typename ...T> Lunch(T...) {} }; 

// and this instead of the for loop
Lunch{ (CheckLuaValue<Params>(), void(), 0)... };
```

You can do something else with a lambda. You can even have your `i` incremented

```
static int CFunctionWrapper (lua_State* luaState)
{
    int i = 0;
    Lunch{ 
      (CheckLuaValue<Params>(), 
       [&]{ std::cout << "That was param " << i << std::endl; }(),
       ++i)... 
    };
}
```

Note that the Standard supports putting everything into the lambda. Compiler support until recently (last time I checked) wasn't very good though

```
static int CFunctionWrapper (lua_State* luaState)
{
    int i = 0;
    Lunch{([&]{ 
       CheckLuaValue<Params>();
       std::cout << "That was param " << i << std::endl;
    }(), ++i)... 
    };
}
```

Comment: Isn't this UB thanks to function argument evaluation not having a specified order? I'd use a (temporary) array instead: `alias<int[]>{(..., ++i)...}`.

Comment: @Xeo it is not UB: When using a `{...}`, the order is defined even if it results in a function call. Note that your proposal will fail when `Params` is empty (array of zero size requested).

Comment: Ah, good to know. And the zero-case could easily be fixed by having a dummy `0` before the expansion.

Comment: using this gives me a linker `error: undefined reference to 'MyNamespace::Lunch::Lunch<int, int>(int, int)'` (where `int, int` is the expanded template type).

Comment: The code suggests this description: A struct with a variadic template member is declared,`Lunch{ template<typename ...T> Lunch(T...){} }`.Thru list initialization, anonymous `Lunch` objects are constructed, initialized with the parenthesized triple `(CheckLuaValue<Params>(), void(), 0)`.In the lambda version, the fcn within the triple is evaluated for every `Params` entry.Similarly for the triple's final sequent, a counter `( .... , ++i)...`.The 2nd lambda example contracts the triple. The design is possible as evaluation within the braces is ordered(unlike for a function argument list)