# Applying a lambda to template arguments pack; lambda arguments not captured

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I want to write a function that will accept any number of numeric arguments and return their mean. Using an expansion trick from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template):

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename... Args> void iterate_template_pack(Args&&...) {}
}

template <typename ResultType, typename... Args>
ResultType arithmeticMean(Args&&... args)
{
    ResultType acc = ResultType(0);
    size_t n = 0;

    detail::iterate_template_pack(([&](){
        acc += ResultType(args);
        ++n;
    })...);

    return acc / n;
}
```

This compiles and almost works: I can see the lambda receiving args one by one correctly. However, the `acc` and `n` are not modified. How so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the lambda, otherwise you're just passing a series of lambda objects to `iterate_template_pack`:

```
detail::iterate_template_pack(([&](){
    acc += ResultType(args);
    ++n;
})()...);
  ^^
```

Since your lambda doesn't have a return value, you also need to supply a value to pass to `iterate_template_pack`, as you can't pass `void` as an argument:

```
detail::iterate_template_pack((([&](){
    acc += ResultType(args);
    ++n;
})(), void(), 0)...);
```

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) (my emphasis):

> Instead of executing a function, a lambda expression may be specified *and executed in place*, which allows executing arbitrary sequences of statements in-place.
>
> ```
> pass{([&]{ std::cout << args << std::endl; }(), 1)...};
> ```

Note that gcc fails to compile the above because of [PR 47226](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47226) (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13444602/34509). One workaround is to expand the parameter pack outside the lambda:

```
detail::iterate_template_pack((([&](ResultType&& r){
    acc += r;
    ++n;
}(args)), void(), 0)...);
```

Comment: Oh... How did it even compile? What did my code compile into? Did it just construct 2 `function` objects?

Comment: Well, your suggestion gives me ICE (msvc, v110 toolset) :)

Comment: I don't understand this syntax you've just suggested at all, can you please explain?

Comment: That Wiki quote is for a different trick - `struct pass`, not function.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe it's the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other). The `void()` is strictly unnecessary, but it's useful in general when using the comma operator, as it can't be overloaded on either side so ensures that the built-in comma operator is used.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe `struct pass` is an improvement on a `pass` function as it guarantees LTR evaluation. The issue with `void` return value still holds - "*Moreover, this above solution will only work when the return type of `some_function` is not `void`.*"

Comment: So in this case `1` is merely a value that will be the result of the comma operator, making the result type`int`? And the lambda is executed in the process of comma operator evaluation, because it can't simply be evaluated as an argument of `iterate_template_pack`  due to `void` return type?

Comment: The suggested code doesn't compile with GCC 4.9. Any idea why or how to fix it?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Looks like https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47226 - I'll have a think about a workaround

Comment: Thanks! I was just thinking about the same solution, but wasn't sure if it'll work (because I still don't understand the arguments pack expansion mechanics).